# add quotations in mysql table via php

Tags: php, mysql

```
$sql_images = "'".$uploaded_image."', '".$uploaded_image2."', '".$uploaded_image3."', '".$uploaded_image4."', '".$uploaded_image5."'";

$db->query("UPDATE menu SET nav_name = $navigation, image_bg = $sql_images WHERE id = $id;") or die(mysql_error());
```

I cant update my table and I know that the problem is with the $sql_images variable because I have added quotations and have messed it all up, but that is how I want and need it, is there any way to add that variable in the table without any problem? because right now it gives me an error.

Comment: "because right now it gives me an error" --- and the error is? When you come to doctor - do you explain your issue or just sit in the chair and wait until he guesses what's happened?

Comment: @zerkms here is the error:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''webcam-toy-photo3.jpg', 'webcam-toy-photo2.jpg', 'webcam-toy-photo1.jpg', '1901' at line 1

Comment: put the exact sql query you're performing (without any php code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this

```
$sql_images = "\'".$uploaded_image."\', \'".$uploaded_image2."\', \'".$uploaded_image3."\', \'".$uploaded_image4."\', \'".$uploaded_image5."\'";

$db->query("UPDATE menu SET nav_name = '$navigation', image_bg = '$sql_images' WHERE id = $id;") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: #Zoltan Toth thank you, this did the trick, I dont know why I didnt came up with this myself :/ anyway thank you a lot

Comment: @Zoltan Toth: why did you add slashes for single quotes? How is it different from `"'"`?

Comment: @zerkms because the final concatenated `$sql_images` looks like this `'image1', 'image2', 'image3', 'image4'` and when you insert a text value like this into SQL it needs quotes around. So it reads `'image1'` and treats it's second closing quote as the closing quote for the whole value that will be inserted. And then you have the 3 other images which give you the parse error..

Comment: @Zoltan Toth: oh, I thought there are 4 different string literals there, not a single long string with comma separated quoted names :-S

Comment: @zerkms вижу зря так детально объяснял - PHP программеру-то :)

Comment: @Zoltan Toth: yep :-S Just missed the fact it's the only field there - I couldn't even imagine anyone would want to store the data in such a strange format. But people amaze me every day ;-)